# objdump do not show machine code, but show asm

Tags: c++, c, objdump

I have a simple cpp program in main.cpp:

```cpp
int factorial(int n) {
  int result = 1;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    result *= i;
  }
  return result;
}

int main() {
  factorial(10);
}
```

One can get an object file (main.o) out of this as:

> g++ -c -g main.cpp

One can then run objdump on this `main.o` to see the assembly code and machine code along with the source code:

> objdump -S  -M intel main.o | less

that looks like this:

```
0000000000000000 <_Z9factoriali>:
int factorial(int n) {
   0:   55                      push   rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
   4:   89 7d ec                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],edi
  int result = 1;
   7:   c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
   e:   c7 45 f8 01 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x1
  15:   8b 45 f8                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  18:   3b 45 ec                cmp    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14]
  1b:   7f 0f                   jg     2c <_Z9factoriali+0x2c>
    result *= i;
  1d:   8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
  20:   0f af 45 f8             imul   eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  24:   89 45 fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],eax
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
  27:   ff 45 f8                inc    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  2a:   eb e9                   jmp    15 <_Z9factoriali+0x15>
  }
  return result;
  2c:   8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
}
  2f:   5d                      pop    rbp
  30:   c3                      ret
```

Is it possible that I can get an output like this: (abbr)

```
0000000000000000 <_Z9factoriali>:
int factorial(int n) {
   push   rbp                   
   mov    rbp,rsp               
   mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],edi
  int result = 1;
   mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
   mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x1
   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
   cmp    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14]
   jg     2c <_Z9factoriali+0x2c>
  result *= i;
   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
   imul   eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
   mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],eax
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
   inc    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
   jmp    15 <_Z9factoriali+0x15>
  }
  return result;
   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
}
  pop    rbp                    
  ret
```

i.e. without machine code. I looked at the man page, and couldn't find an option like that.

Is there another tool which can show me the assembly intermingled with the source code? I know that many IDEs like visual studio has this feature built in.

Btw, one way is using `gdb` and then call `disassemble /m func_name` and that produces what I need, but it is too much work to start gdb and run that command.

Comment: Did you try the -S flag with g++? `g++ -S main.cpp`. You can also disassembe to intel syntax by specifying `-masm=intel`

Comment: @TonyTannous I did, but it doesn't produce the intermingled output that I am looking for.

Comment: You can run gdb in batch mode: `gdb -ex "disassemble /m factorial(int)" main.o`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From manpage of objdump,

> --no-show-raw-insn
>              When disassembling instructions, do not print the instruction bytes.  This is the default when --prefix-addresses is used.

So, `objdump -S -M intel --no-show-raw-insn main.o | less` should do the trick.

Comment: This gets us super close to what I need. It shows the pesky offsets `0:`, `1:`...

Comment: @skgbanga Use `cut` command: `objdump -S -M intel --no-show-raw-insn main.o | cut -d ':' -f 2-`